# Implementing oEmbed discovery with a static link

Tags: javascript, standards, service-discovery, oembed

The [oEmbed spec](https://oembed.com/#section4) requires a site to link to its oEmbed endpoint *and* encode the current URL in that link. This is quite annoying for static/CDN-served websites that have to now encoding/return the request URL into the HTML response.

I'm wondering if it is known whether major oEmbed consumers (e.g. Slack, Facebook, or oEmbed client libraries) will add this URL themselves when requesting, so much so that it may be reasonable, in practice, to break the spec and do this statically. Any examples of a static implementation could be insightful.

Dynamic:
`Link: <http://flickr.com/services/oembed?url=http%3A%2F%2Fflickr.com%2Fphotos%2Fbees%2F2362225867%2F&format=json>; rel="alternate"; type="application/json+oembed"; title="Bacon Lollys oEmbed Profile"`

Static:
`Link: <http://flickr.com/services/oembed?format=json>; rel="alternate"; type="application/json+oembed"; title="Bacon Lollys oEmbed Profile"`

Comment: did you ever get an answer to this? I'm struggling with the same problem

Comment: I wasn't able to find a solution, only way seems to be to server render :(

Comment: Hey @LeonRadley, I actually went ahead and implemented the discovery mechanism and the oEmbed endpoint and it worked fine in Slack. I was using ngrok for my dev environment and I think they must just blacklist ngrok domains or ngrok blacklists their user agents. Give it a shot and see if it works for your usecase too!

Comment: @NikhilShinday How where you able to implement the discovery into the endpoint?
Where were you able to get the url param from?

Comment: Answered the original question you were asking below :)

Answer (score 1):

I implemented discovery using the  html tag alternative (as opposed to the Link header).

Our frontend services are deployed by having an NGINX container serve up static build files. I wanted to add oEmbed discovery to all responses, so I used `ndk_http_module` and `ngx_http_set_misc_module` to create an escaped URI variable then inject it as a tag at the end of the  html element. My experience after playing around with it for a few days on platforms like Slack and Teams is that including the URL query parameter and the format haven't conflicted so far.

Our frontend services are deployed by having an NGINX container serve up static build files. I wanted to add oEmbed discovery to all responses, so I used `ndk_http_module` and `ngx_http_set_misc_module` to create an escaped URI variable then injected it as a tag at the end of the  html element like so:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  set_escape_uri $escaped_uri $http_host$request_uri;
  sub_filter '</head>' '<link rel=\"alternate\" type=\"application/json+oembed\" href=\"${OEMBED_URL}?format=json&amp;url=https%3A%2F%2F$escaped_uri\" title=\"Bacon Lollys oEmbed Profile\"></head>';
  ...
}
```